# Viewport colors look darker in Vertex Paint mode Blender 2.8

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-paint

Viewport shading set to solid and color to vertex with flat shading,
the colors appear to be darker in vertex paint mode than in object mode.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default vertex colors get multiplied when entering vertex paint mode.
Set opacity of vertex paint mode overlay to 0 in viewport overlays to make object and vertex paint mode look the same.
[image]